# Intellij IDEA: How to disable linebreak animation before method

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I disable line break animation before method `testTest()` and `arr`?
(Marked by red arrows)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the **Show method separators** option:

[image: appearance]